# Spring Data JPA - ZonedDateTime format for json serialization

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with the json serialization of `ZonedDateTime`. When converted to json it produces an enormous object and I don't want all that data to be transfered every time. So i tried to format it to ISO but it doesn't work. How can i get it to format?

Here is my Entity Class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AuditBase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @CreatedDate
    private ZonedDateTime createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private ZonedDateTime lastModifiedDate;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    public ZonedDateTime getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedDate(ZonedDateTime lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    public ZonedDateTime getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(ZonedDateTime createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        this.createdDate = ZonedDateTime.now();
        this.lastModifiedDate = ZonedDateTime.now();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate() {
        this.lastModifiedDate = ZonedDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I guess that you are using Jackson for json serialization, Jackson now has a module for Java 8 new date time API, https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310.

Add this dependency into your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And this is its usage:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Entity()));
}

static class Entity {
    ZonedDateTime time = ZonedDateTime.now();

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    public ZonedDateTime getTime() {
        return time;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
{"time":"2015-07-25T23:09:01.795+0700"}
```

Note : If your Jackson version is 2.4.x use

```
objectMapper.registerModule(new JSR310Module());
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had something very strange:
{"time":1473923145.038000000}.
With your solution I now have
{"time":"2016-09-15T07:57:26.602+0000"}
as desired.

Comment: For me it was enough with registerModule. I didn't have to touch the entity. Thanks!!

Comment: I always get the chills when some one post a 5 lines of XML from a pom file, Gralde for the win ;)

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek: fair enough, Gradle looks more succinct, sometimes we just need to make it work though.

Comment: @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", timezone = "UTC") => 2019-10-16T08:23:51.817Z

Comment: `JSR310Module ` was deprecated in favour of `JavaTimeModule()`

Comment: @DaniMedina Yes, it has been deprecated since Jackson 2.5

Answer (score 3):

Above answer works but if you don't want to touch  your existing entity class, following settings will work with `ZonedDateTime` :

```
  public static ObjectMapper getMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());    
    return mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false)
.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS,false)
                        .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS,false)
                        .configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)
                        .setVisibility(mapper.getSerializationConfig()
                                .getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
                                .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
                                .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                                .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                                .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)); 
    }
```

Library:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.dataformat.csv.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the problem setting the following property to `application.yml`.

```yaml
    spring:
      jackson:
        serialization:
          write_dates_as_timestamps: false
```

I use `spring-boot:2.3.8.RELEASE` and `dependency-management:1.0.10.RELEASE`.

For more detailed information [see this link.](https://touk.pl/blog/2016/02/12/formatting-java-time-with-spring-boot-using-json/)

Comment: Doesn't work with spring boot version 2.7.5!