# How to specify UTC timezone for Spring Boot JPA Timestamp

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-boot, timezone

**Environment**

- Spring Boot Starter Data JPA 1.4.2
- Eclipselink 2.5.0
- Postgresql 9.4.1211.jre7

**Problem**

I am building a Spring Boot microservice that shares a Postgresql database with a different service. The database gets initialized externally (out of our control) and the datetime column type used by the other service is **timestamp without time zone**. Therefore, since I want all dates on the db to have the same type, having that type is a requirement for my JPA entity dates.

The way I map them on my JPA entity objects is as follows:

```
@Column(name = "some_date", nullable = false)
private Timestamp someDate;
```

The problem is that when I create a Timestamp as follows:

```
new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
```

and I look at the database, the timestamp contains my local timezone date time, but I want to store it in UTC. This is because my default Timezone is set to 'Europe/Brussels' and JPA/JDBC converts my `java.sql.Timestamp` object into my timezone before putting it into the database.

**Found not ideal solutions**

- `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));` has the effect that I want to achieve, but it's not suitable because it is not specific to my service. I.e. it will affect the whole JVM or the current thread plus children.
- Starting the application with `-Duser.timezone=GMT` seems to also do the job for a single instance of a running JVM. Therefore, a better solution than the previous one.

But is there a way to specify the timezone within the JPA/datasource/spring boot configuration?

Comment: How do you "look at the database"? Perhaps it's just PostgreSQL adjusting the timestamp to your session's timezone? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/466738).

Comment: Thanks for answering @Adam, I just `SELECT * FROM my_table`. According to the answer you linked, _"when you later display that timestamp, you get back what you entered literally"_. If I `SELECT my_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' FROM 
my_table` I see the same result, which makes sense.

Considering that, I would assume that it is not PostgreSQL adjusting the timezone, the adjustment seems to happen before the value gets into the db on the Java side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most appropriate workaround I could figure out for the problem is to use an `AttributeConverter` to convert Java 8 `ZonedDateTime` objects into `java.sql.Timestamp` objects, so that they can be mapped to the PostgreSQL `timestamp without time zone` type.

The reason why you need an `AttributeConverter` is because the Java 8/Joda time date time types [are not yet compatible with JPA](https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-63).

The `AttributeConverter` looks like this:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class ZonedDateTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<ZonedDateTime, Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime) {
        return (zonedDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(zonedDateTime.toLocalDateTime()));
    }

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp sqlTimestamp) {
        return (sqlTimestamp == null ? null : sqlTimestamp.toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")));
    }

}
```

This allows me to read the database timestamps that **do not** have timezone information as `ZonedDateTime` objects that have the **UTC** timezone. This way I keep the exact date time that can be seen on the db **regardless of the timezone that my app runs in**.

Since [`toLocalDateTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toLocalDateTime--) also applies the system's default timezone conversion, this `AttributeConverter` basically cancels out the conversion applied by the JDBC driver.

### Do you really need to use `timestamp without timezone`?

The reality is that if you are storing date time information on a time zone (even if it is UTC), the `timestamp without timezone` PostgreSQL type is the wrong choice. The right data type to use would be `timestamp with timezone` which does include the timezone information. More on this topic [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4B2F2CED.10400%40opencloud.com).

However, if for whatever reason, you **must** use the `timestamp without timezone`, I think the `ZonedDateTime` approach above is a robust and consistent solution.

### Are you also serializing the `ZonedDateTime` to JSON?

Then you are probably interested in the fact that you need at least version `2.6.0` of the `jackson-datatype-jsr310` dependency for the serialization to work. More on that [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31628569/2591744).

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Eclipselink uses the single arg version of `setTimestamp`, delegating responsibility for time zone handling to the driver, and the postgresql jdbc driver doesn't allow the default time zone to be overridden. The postgres driver even propagates the client time zone to the session, so server side defaults will be of no use to you either.

There are some hackish things you could try to work around the problem, for example writing a JPA 2.1 `AttributeConverter` to shift your timestamps into the destination zone, but ultimately they're doomed because your client time zone has daylight savings adjustments, making some times ambiguous or unrepresentable.

You'll have to set the default time zone on your client, or drop into native SQL to set timestamps as strings with casts.

Answer (score 0):

What about using Instant, instead of LocalDateTime? I think it may convert entity value to timestamp, in UTC

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class ZonedDateTimeAttributeConverter implements         AttributeConverter<ZonedDateTime, Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime) {
            return (zonedDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.from(zonedDateTime.toInstant()));
    }

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp sqlTimestamp) {
        return (sqlTimestamp == null ? null : sqlTimestamp.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")));
    }

}
```