# Oracle db not showing correct timezone offset

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

When using JPA to persist Calendar values to the DB, our test environments are storing the current (i.e. today's) offset rather than the offset on the date we're storing.

For example...

**EndDate    /     CreationDate (of db record)**

24-APR-22 23.59.00.000000 +00:00  / 25-MAR-22 11.15.40.813790 +00:00

28-MAR-22 23.59.00.000000 +01:00  /  28-MAR-22 12.20.56.779806 +01:00

In my local environment I do not have this issue as the timezone is stored as the geographic region i.e. 'Europe/London'.

The field(s) are defined as TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE in all environments.

It seems to be writing the wrong offset despite the Calendar object having the correct value e.g. Apr 24 23:59:00 **BST** 2022

Does anyone know how we can enforce that the test environment db tables use geographical regions rather than numeric offsets?

Comment: You probably need to add which DB/column type are you using to the question.

Comment: Ok Ale. Will do.

Comment: This may be of some help too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618165/how-to-specify-utc-timezone-for-spring-boot-jpa-timestamp?rq=1

Comment: Did you try Java options, e.g. `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Duser.language=en -Duser.timezone=Europe/Zurich`