# Rest API call returns error with LocalDate

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot, jackson-databind

I am trying to make a rest api call but keeps getting `400 Bad Request`. From the logs, it seems that there is a problem with one of the `LocalDate` fields of my POJO.

My POJO:

```
public class MyObj implements Serializable {
private Long id;
private String remark;
private LocalDate someDate;
...other fields, getter and setter
```

In my `main()`

```
MyObj myObj = new MyObj();
myObj .setRemark("My test case");
myObj .setSomeDate( LocalDate.now());
...

 WebResource webResource = client
                .resource("my_url");

        webResource
                .header("apikey", "mykey")
                .accept("application/json")
                .type("application/json")
                .post(MyObj.class, myObj );
```

Running the above code I get the following error:
`Bad Request: JSON parse error: Expected array or string.; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Expected array or string.
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 159] (through reference chain: com.xxx.MyObj["someDate"])`

Any idea why the above happened?

Comment: as the error says expected array or string and what you are passing is a LocaleDate object in your POJO make it a String and in the code level may be have a LocaleDate object for the same and use toString().

Comment: Can you add the JSON structure produced by `my_url` to your question? Jackson expects the format to be `[2019, 6, 6]` or `"2019-06-06"` if I'm not mistaken, and I assume that your REST service isn't doing that.

Answer (score 2):

LocalDate should be converted to string on serialization and converted back to LocalDate on deserialization. For that purpose you can use `@JsonDeserialize` and `@JsonSerialize` on object LocalDate property(ies)

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDate someDate;
```

For more information refer to this link:
https://kodejava.org/how-to-format-localdate-object-using-jackson

Another way is to use ObjectMapper and to register modul `JavaTimeModule()`

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

Example of using ObjectMapper and similar problem:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jackson-user/XdHvRKG1vhY

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate your LocalDate to tell how it should be converted to String. Here is a snippet for ZonedDateTime, but all you will need to do is change mask to fit LocalDate.

```
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
public ZonedDateTime getTime() {
    return time;
}
```

Here is the link to the original question: [Spring Data JPA - ZonedDateTime format for json serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627992/spring-data-jpa-zoneddatetime-format-for-json-serialization)