# Why won't the date conversion work in Spring on requests with content-type json-patch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, json-patch

I am getting a "*Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.persistence.Column java.util.Date] for value '1999-12-20'*" when I use json-patch, but I do not get this error with PUT, POST or event PATCH requests with json-merge-patch;

I am using Spring Boot version 2.1.8, with Spring Data Rest.

I have an entity with a field similar to the following (only the name of the variable and column are different):

```
@Column(name = "mydate")
private Date mydate;
```

The field is updated as expected when I issue a JSON merge patch request with the body:

```
{"mydate": "1999-12-20"}
```

It is also updated correctly with POST and PUT requests.

However, if I issue a json-patch with the following command (and Content-Type application/json-patch+json):

```
[{"op":"replace","path":"mydate","value":"2018-08-09"}]
```

I get the error mentioned above.

I don't actually need a workaround for this, as I am using the JSON Merge Patch for that.

I'd like to understand how to make the conversion that works for the other requests work for json-patch as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion: Since Java 8 class `Date` should not be used, and it should be replaced with some implementation of [Temporal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html) interface. For example in your case [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). And as far as Annotations for such property you'd want to annotate it as follows:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
public LocalDate myDate;
```

For details refer to the answer to this question: [Spring Data JPA - ZonedDateTime format for json serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627992/spring-data-jpa-zoneddatetime-format-for-json-serialization)

Comment: I took this opportunity to update all fields to LocalDate. Thanks Michael!  However the issue continues. Regardless of the @JsonFormat annotation, Spring Data Rest correctly updates the field when a PUT is received, but it can't do it for PATCH with JSON-patch Content-Type. I think this may have something to do with the fact that JSON-patch does not uses a structure that follows the entity object.

Comment: I am not familiar with JSON-patch Content-Type. So, I can't help you with this. But the error suggests that JSON doesn't know what format to use to parse the string. Try to figure out how to pass a format to the server-side. That's the best I can do on this issue

Answer (score 1):

**This is a workaround, not a proper solution.**

I still don't understand why this happens, but here are two workarounds that can be helpful for the next poor soul who stumbles in this issue:

**Use JSON Merge Patch**

Patch requests with JSON Merge Patch have their date fields properly interpreted by SDR. If possible, simply switching from using JSON Patch to JSON Merge Patch will solve the situation.

**Use a dummy field**

I couldn't find a way to help Spring Data Rest to use a Converter when it receives a JSON Patch request, so creating a dummy String field in your DTO (or worst ― in your Entity) will fix the issue.

If you can't or don't want to avoid using [json-patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902), this may be helpful.

This is not a beautiful solution and one might call you names upon seeing it, but it will work.

Consider the following ― worst case scenario ― code :

```
@Entity
public class MyRenderVouz {
    ...
    @Column(name="important_date")
    private LocalDate importantDate;
    
    @Transient
    private String strChangeImportantDate;
    public void setStrChangeImportantDate(String newDate) {
        setImportantDate(LocaleDate.parse(newDate);
    }
    public String getStrChangeImportantDate() {
        return this.importantDate;
    }
    ...
}
```

In your JSON-PATCH, simple use the strChangeImportantDate instead of importantDate, for example, consider you want to update the importantDate of the second instance of MyRendezVouz that belong to a calendar:

```
Calendar
 L importantRenderVouz  []
    L myRenderVouz
    L myRenderVouz
        L importantDate // target date
    L myRenderVouz
```

Then you can use:

```
[
    {"op":"replace","path":"importantRenderVouz/1/strImportantDate","value":"2020-01-01"},  
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**What I do when I have to perform patch request for an Entity with LocalDateTime attribute**:

Lets for clarity say that your Entity having attribute LocalDateTime date is modeled with an Event.class:

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "events")
...
public class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long eventId;

    ...

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime date;

    ...
```

**1)** Se externally the LocalDateTime format pattern in application.properties file:

```
config.datetime.format.pattern=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm
```

**2)** Create a class AppConfig.class (or something like that) to extract the value from the application.properties file:

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Value("${config.datetime.format.pattern}")
    private String formatPattern;

    public DateTimeFormatter getDateTimeFormatter(){
        return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formatPattern);
    }
}
```

**3)** Add the AppConfig dependency to your service class:

```java
@Service
public class EventService {
    private final EventRepository eventRepo;
    private final EventDtoMapper eventDtoMapper;
    private final AppConfig appConfig;
    ...

    @Autowired
    public EventService(EventRepository eventRepo, EventDtoMapper eventDtoMapper, AppConfig appConfig, ...) {
        this.eventRepo = eventRepo;
        this.eventDtoMapper = eventDtoMapper;
        this.appConfig = appConfig;
        ...
    }
```

**4)** Write the service code for the function that will do the partial update:

```java
 public EventDtoForCreate updatePartially(Long id, Map<String, String> fields) {
        Optional<Event> found = eventRepo.findById(id);

        if (found.isEmpty()) {
            // custom exception
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Failed to find event");
        }

        fields.forEach((key, value) -> {
            Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(Event.class, key);
            if (field != null) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                if (field.getAnnotatedType().getType().equals(LocalDateTime.class)) {
                    ReflectionUtils.setField(field, found.get(), LocalDateTime.parse(value, appConfig.getDateTimeFormatter()));
                } else {
                    ReflectionUtils.setField(field, found.get(), value);
                }
            }
        });

        return eventDtoMapper.toDtoCreate(eventRepo.save(found.get()));
    }
```

**5)** Finally, create the controller for the patch request:

```java
    @PatchMapping(
            value = "/{id}",
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}
    )
    public ResponseEntity<EventDtoCreate> updatePartially(
            @PathVariable(name = "id") Long userId,
            @RequestBody Map<String, String> fields
    ) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(eventService.updatePartially(userId, fields));
    }
```