# Format date and time using Thymeleaf and java

Tags: java, spring, datetime, timestamp, thymeleaf

I have date and time saved in database using timestamp format, so it looks like this: 2022-03-18 14:15:09.011.
Also in class WoundedPerson I have this:
`@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") private Date addAt;` and create date using function `new Date()`.

I try to get date and time of specific person from database to website using Thymeleaf.
So I get data of person: `<input type="hidden" name="addAt" th:value="${woundedPerson.getAddAt()}">`

Then I processed it in controller adding to model and add to website using `<h3 th:text="${woundedPerson.getAddAt()}"></h3>`

But on website show something like this format: Mon Mar 14 22:29:58 CET 2022, but I want a format look like in a database or something like that. It means that I want only date and time, not name of day and CET.

How can I do that?

Comment: Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65273023/datetimeformatpattern-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-is-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Use #temporals in Thymeleaf like that:

```html
<h3 th:text="${#temporals.format(woundedPerson.getAddAt(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}"></h3>
```