# How to deserialize date '2017-01-01T00:00:59.000UTC'

Tags: java, json, date

Trying to deserialize date with specific pattern from json file.
Object which I want to receive from json file:

```java
@Data
public class MyClass {
  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'UTC'")
  @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
  private LocalDateTime date;
}
```

Json file:

```json
{
  "date" : "2017-01-01T00:00:59.000UTC"
}
```

Code example how I want to receive it:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyClass clazz = mapper.readValue(new File("MyFile.json"), MyClass.class);
```

Actual result:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: 
Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String "2017-01-01T00:00:59.000UTC":
Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) 
Text '2017-01-01T00:00:59.000UTC' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 23
at [Source: (File); line: 2, column: 11] (through reference chain: com.example.MyClass["date"])
```

How to deserialize current date pattern?

Comment: `2017-01-01T00:00:59.000UTC` is a peculiar mixed format. What’s wrong with the international standard, [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date format that you are using is incorrect.

Instead of: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'UTC'`

it should be: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz`

Secondly, you need to use `@JsonFormat` to specify the date format.

`@JsonFormat` which is defined in [jackson-databind](https://search.maven.org/classic/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.fasterxml.jackson.core%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jackson-databind%22) package gives you more control on how to format Date and Calendar values according to SimpleDateFormat.

By using this, the POJO `MyClass` would look something like this:

```
@Data
public class MyClass {
  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz", timezone = "UTC")
  @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
  private LocalDateTime date;
}
```

Now, if you try to deserialize using:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyClass clazz = mapper.readValue(new File("MyFile.json"), MyClass.class);
System.out.println(myClass);
```

Then the process would go through, producing a result something like this:

```
MyClass{date=2017-01-01T00:00:59.000}
```

Comment: Yes, this configuration works. Following two lines are enough to deserialize this json date:
```@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz")
  @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)``` but we lost the zone.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what did you mean by lost the zone?

Answer (score 2):

Your date is in incorrect format (with UTC as text simply appended), but you can solve it by custom formatter.

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MyClass localDateTime = objectMapper.readValue("{\"date\":\"2017-01-01T00:00:59.000UTC\"}", MyClass.class);
    System.out.println(localDateTime.date);
  }

  @Data
  public static class MyClass {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime date;

  }

  public static class CustomDeserializer extends LocalDateTimeDeserializer {

    public CustomDeserializer() {
      super(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
    }

    protected CustomDeserializer(LocalDateTimeDeserializer base, Boolean leniency) {
      super(base, leniency);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
      String substring = jsonParser.getText().substring(0, jsonParser.getText().indexOf("U"));
      return LocalDateTime.parse(substring, _formatter);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: UTC is a Zone. It is not simply appended

Comment: this example also works but we lost a zone again

Answer (score 0):

Try removing  `@JsonDeserialize`. (In any case, you are trying to deserialize your date into LocalDateTime but it has time zone info, you would need to try ZonedDateTime or OffsetDateTime). And change the line

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'UTC'")
```

to

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
```

Here is the link to the question that has a full answer for you: [Spring Data JPA - ZonedDateTime format for json serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627992/spring-data-jpa-zoneddatetime-format-for-json-serialization)

Comment: for `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` doesn't work throws following error:
```com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.ZonedDateTime` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2017-01-01T00:00:59.000UTC')``` Because deserializer class is required. And there is no default deserializer classes provided for these type of date classes.

Comment: Try to change 'Z' to 'O' in mask. So your mask would be "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSO". See Javadoc for class DateTimeFormatter