# Api Error showing timestamp as showing milliseconds not Date in Spring Boot (Jsonformat not working)

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, localdate

I have a problem about showing timestamp as a Date in Spring boot.

I always get timestamp as an int value shown below.

```
"timestamp": 1646735268046
```

How can I get it as a Date?

Here is my ApiError entity shown below.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ApiError implements Serializable {

    private int statusCode;

    private HttpStatus status;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", timezone = "GMT")
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;

    private String message;

    List<String> errorDetails;

}
```

Here is a function defined in Global Exception Handling class shown below.

```
    @ExceptionHandler(UserNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleRefreshTokenException(RefreshTokenException ex) {

        List<String> details = new ArrayList<String>();
        details.add(ex.getMessage());

        ApiError err = new ApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, LocalDateTime.now() ,
                "User Not Found", details);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(err);
    }
```

Edited:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
```

I still get int value.

Comment: first of all, you are getting `long` not `int`. Integers in Java can have max of `2^31 - 1`.

can you please mention spring/boot version, if you are using that, that way we can know what jackson version you are using, OR are you using jackson explicitely (or something else)?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `LocalDateTime` but in your format you have 'Z' which is zone-offset which is not supported by `LocalDateTime`. So either change to `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` or remove 'Z' from your format. Other than that I don't see any problems. Anyway here is a [link to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627992/spring-data-jpa-zoneddatetime-format-for-json-serialization) with a very good answer on this topic

Comment: I remove 'Z' but I still get int value as a timestamp.

Comment: Time zone is also irrelevant for LocalDateTime, try removing this also, or just for test bring back your Z and cjange LocalDateTime to OffsetDateTime see if any of those 2 options fix your problem

Comment: I use this format (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) but nothing changed.

Comment: but did you remove timezone = "GMT"?

Comment: Yes, I removed it.

Comment: I don't have other ideas.

Comment: Have you ever tested it?

Comment: Not your code from here but I used this annotation many many times and it worked for me always

Comment: I already defined jackson-databind dependency to use this option but I still get this result. ("timestamp": 1646821108362)

Comment: I am surprised by that, it looks now as if it should work. I did use the same construct many times and it worked. I don'r have any other ideas in your case. Except in your format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" try to change it to "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss" or "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" sometimes the format may not like spaces

Comment: It's probably due to the exception handler not using ResponseBody semantics, try adding @ResponseBody to the handleRefreshTokenException method