# Getting null values inside a response wrapper class when tried to deserialize in Rest Assured

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

I am trying to catch and validate the response of an API but when I tried to debug the same, I am getting null values inside each of the variables of the developer DTO I am trying to reuse. Below is the code I am trying to use.

```
ValidatableResponse response = given().header("Authorization", token).header("Content-type", "application/json")
                .when().log().all().pathParam("CalendarId", testCaseBean.getCalendarId().toString()).urlEncodingEnabled(false)
                .queryParam("from", testCaseBean.getStartDate()).queryParam("to", testCaseBean.getEndDate())
                .queryParam("monthEnd", testCaseBean.getMonthEndBusinessDay())
                .get(EndPoint.GET_CALENDAR_DETAILS_BY_MULTIPLE_CALENDAR_CODE).then().log().all();

        InCalendarDateResponseWrapper actualRIOutput = CommonUtils.getJSONMapper()
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                .readValue(response.extract().asString(), InCalendarDateResponseWrapper .class);
        String t=actualRIOutput.getCalendarId();
```

The value of t when I am trying to print, I am getting null. Below is the developer DTO.

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.time.LocalDate;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ToString
public class InCalendarDateResponseWrapper {

    private String calendarId;

    private LocalDate calDat;

    private LocalDate prevBus;

    private LocalDate nextBus;

    private Boolean bus;

    private Boolean  monthEnd;

}
```

The response of the GET API is as follows.

```
{
    "EU": [
        {
            "calendarId": "EU",
            "calDat": "2022-11-01",
            "prevBus": "2022-10-31",
            "nextBus": "2022-11-02",
            "bus": true,
            "monthEnd": false
        }
    ],
    "AU": [
        {
            "calendarId": "AU",
            "calDat": "2022-11-01",
            "prevBus": "2022-10-31",
            "nextBus": "2022-11-02",
            "bus": true,
            "monthEnd": false
        }
    ]
}
```

The getJSONMapper code which I am using is as follows.

```
public static ObjectMapper getJSONMapper() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        return objectMapper;
    }
```

Am I doing any mistake in catching the response? The response is returned by the API on the console when I do log().all() but when I try to fetch the response deserializing it, I see null values inside each of my variables one of them I have printed and it gives null on the console.

Comment: you want to convert all response to object but you missed one level. I don't see `EU` or `AU` in your DTO.

Comment: So how should I build new DTO?

Answer (score 0):

You need one more object.

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@Data
public class Wrapper {
    @JsonProperty("EU")
    private List<InCalendarDateResponseWrapper> EU;
    
    @JsonProperty("AU")
    private List<InCalendarDateResponseWrapper> AU;
}
```

To convert JSON to DTO

```java
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
...
Wrapper wrapper = JsonPath.from(res).getObject("", Wrapper.class);
String t = actualRIOutput.getEU().get(0).getCalendarId();
```

Comment: Still getting null

Comment: Instead of AU and EU being hardcoded in the bean, can we make that response dynamic in the bean itself? Because those values are displayed as per what we add in the GET request query and path parameters. So I want to behave the code like whatever I pass in the path or query parameters, we should be able to fetch the response.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the line

```
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
```

You will need to annotate your `LocalDate` properties with annotation as follows:

```
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate calDat;
```

Please see this question and answer for detailed explanation: [Spring Data JPA - ZonedDateTime format for json serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627992/spring-data-jpa-zoneddatetime-format-for-json-serialization)