# Proper way to automatically deserialise a LocalDateTime request param in Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, java-time

What is the proper (recommended/documented) way to automatically deserialise a LocalDateTime request param in **Spring Boot 3**.

The url looks like http://localhost:8080/test?from=20221001000000

I have tried this solution and it does not work

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public String index(@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "YYYYMMddHHmmss") java.time.LocalDateTime from) {
.....
}
```

I have tried this and it does not work neither. It does not even enter the custom deserialiser.

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public String index(@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class) LocalDateTime from) {
........
}

@Override
public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        ....
    }
```

The exception that I get is

`[org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' from required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime'; Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDateTime] for value '20221001000000']`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data JPA - ZonedDateTime format for json serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627992/spring-data-jpa-zoneddatetime-format-for-json-serialization)

Answer (score 1):

It seems your pattern is not correct, try this instead:

```
uuuuMMddHHmmss
```

- `uuuu` for the year
- `MM` for the month month
- `dd` for the day
- `HH` for an hours in a 24-hour format
- `mm` for minutes
- `ss` for seconds

Your code can look like this

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public String index(@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "uuuuMMddHHmmss") LocalDateTime from) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTimeFormat should be "y" for Year and not "Y". See the DateTimeFormat ISO format documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.ISO.html