# ObjectMapper returns null value on date field

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

My data is as below and saved in test folder with name risk.json

```
[{
    "Risk": "BN",
    "Classification": null,
    "LastDefaultDate": "1915-04-14 00:00:00"
  }]
```

I have RiskClass defined as below

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"document"})
public class RiskClass implements KeyedObject {

    String risk;
    String classification;
    Date lastDefaultDate;

    @Override
    public String getKey() {
        return risk;
    }
}
```

In my data prepare class i am trying to populate one of the map by doing below

```
List<RiskClass> rList = ObjectUtils.jsonStringToObjList(readFileAsString("test", "risk.json"), RiskClass.class);
Map<String, RiskClass> riskMapLocal = new HashMap<>();
for (RiskClass rMap : rList) {
    riskMapLocal.put(rMap.getRisk(), rMap);
}
```

now when i try to print riskMapLocal, under lastDefaultDate i get null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an annotation over your property `lastDefaultDate`:

```
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    LocalDateTime lastDefaultDate;
```

Also change type `Date` to `LocalDateTime` as Date type is outdated (pun intended). For more details look at this question and its best answer: [Spring Data JPA - ZonedDateTime format for json serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627992/spring-data-jpa-zoneddatetime-format-for-json-serialization)

Answer (score 2):

Property names in json start with uppercase - `Risk`, etc. Fields in POJO start with lowercase - `risk`, so they can't be matched automatically. You can either:

1. Change them in json to be lowercase
2. Use annotation [JsonProperty](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) on the fields to specify the name of the property to match for this field.

```
public class RiskClass {

  @JsonProperty("Risk")
  String risk;
}
```