# How deserialize from json to java object?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My problem is that I need to deserialize my json response from the server into a java object, but the problem is that after deserialization, there are only null in the set fields. The answer from the server checked the filled fields come. What am I doing wrong and how to fix it? Thanks for the help.

This my method service

```
 public ReportDataFromReporter getReports(int weekNumber, int year) throws JsonProcessingException {
    LocalDate mondayOfWeek = LocalDate.of(year, Month.JUNE, 1)
            .with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY))
            .with(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, weekNumber);
    LocalDate sundayOfWeek = mondayOfWeek.plusDays(6);
    String url = "example.com";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    objectMapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    ObjectForRequestToReporter objectForRequestToReporter = new ObjectForRequestToReporter();
    objectForRequestToReporter.setToken(userService.getUser().getReporterToken());
    objectForRequestToReporter.setEmployee(userService.getUser().getLogin());
    objectForRequestToReporter.setFrom(mondayOfWeek);
    objectForRequestToReporter.setTo(sundayOfWeek);
    String jsonObject = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objectForRequestToReporter);
    System.out.println(jsonObject);
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    httpHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonObject, httpHeaders);
    String reporterResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, String.class);
    ReportDataFromReporter reportDataFromReporter = objectMapper
            .readValue(reporterResponse, ReportDataFromReporter.class);
    System.out.println(reportDataFromReporter);
    return reportDataFromReporter;
```

this is the Java object I need to deserialize into

```
 @Data
 public class ReportDataFromReporter {
private Long id;
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate day;
private Integer hours;
private String description;
private Long project;
private Long taskType;
private Long work_after;
 }
```

This response from external api in json

```
 {
   "reports": [
     {
      "id": somenumber,
  "date": "2023-03-15T00:00:00+03:00",
  "hour": "sometext",
  "text": "sometext",
  "pro": somenumber,
  "task": somenumber,
},
{
  "id": somenumber,
  "date": "2023-03-15T00:00:00+03:00",
  "hour": "sometext",
  "text": "sometext",
  "pro": somenumber,
  "task": somenumber,
},
{
   "id": somenumber,
  "date": "somedate",
  "hour": "sometext",
  "text": "sometext",
  "pro": somenumber,
  "task": somenumber,
},
{
"id": somenumber,
  "date": "2023-03-15T00:00:00+03:00",
  "hour": "sometext",
  "text": "sometext",
  "pro": somenumber,
  "task": somenumber,
     }
   ]
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your properties of your class match the name of your files in Json. Also the `date` field in Json should be mapped to `OffsetDateTime` type or ZonedDateTime. To properly map your date field see the answer to this question for more details: [Spring Data JPA - ZonedDateTime format for json serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627992/spring-data-jpa-zoneddatetime-format-for-json-serialization). As for the unmatching properties to field names you should use @JsonProperty annotation. For instance instead of

```
private Long project;
```

use

```
@JsonProperty("pro")
private Long project;
```

This will tell ObjectMapper to map field "pro" to property "project". See  this article: [Jackson Annotation Examples](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations)

Comment: i have a problem not only with date, after desirialize every fields is null

Comment: I updated my answer to address your problem

Comment: I added annotation @JsonProperty for every field in my java object, but there still is null

Comment: Your Json string is a list and not a single value. So, try to change  the line:
ReportDataFromReporter reportDataFromReporter = objectMapper
            .readValue(reporterResponse, ReportDataFromReporter.class);
to
List<ReportDataFromReporter> = objectMapper
            .readValue(reporterResponse, List.class); 
But I suspect that you will get List<Map> and not List<ReportDataFromReporter>. So in this case you will need to go over every map in the list and convert it to ReportDataFromReporter

Comment: can u help one more time
how i can convert it to ReportDataFromReporter?

Comment: If you get a list of maps, the simple way would be to add a constructor in your class ReportDataFromReporter that takes a map as a parameter and sets all its properties from values it reads from the map.